# jquery show div on hover in php cicle from database

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm actually facing a problem with div ids while generating a product list.
I'm using a fade in effect and hide effect on a text link

here is a portion of code:

javascript

```
$('.theLink').hover(
    function () {
        $('.theDiv').fadeIn();
    },
    function () {
        $('.theDiv').hide();
    });
```

css

```
.theDiv {
    display: none;
    margin-top:-7px;
    background-color:#fff;
    width: 148px;
    line-height:100%;
    border:1px solid #c3c3c3;
    background:#fff;
    -moz-border-radius:3px;
    -webkit-border-radius:3px;
    border-radius:3px;
    position: relative;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

html

```
<div class="theLink">Compatibilit&agrave;</div>    
<div class="theDiv">' . $something . '</div>
```

variabile `$something` works correctly and display correct detail on each item in products the list
When i go over `theLink` it opens `theDiv` in each item of the list instead of only the current one with i'm over.

I hope to have been clear. Thanks in advance for any help.

ADDED:

I'm going to add the implemented code to let you understand where the part is placed

```
<div class="content">
    <div class="bordobasso">
        <div class="theLink">
            <div class="compatibilita">Compatibilit&agrave;</div>
        </div>
        <div class="dettagliprodotto">Acquista</div>
    </div>
</div><div class="theDiv">' . $new_products['products_id'] . '</div>
```

`content` already have another jquery function to expand item from the list and place some css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

test this:

```
$('.theLink').hover(
    function () {
        $(this).closest('.content').next('.theDiv').fadeIn();
    },
    function () {
        $(this).closest('.content').next('.theDiv').hide();
});
```

the 'this' variable indicates in which element jquery looks for the 'theDiv' element

example: http://jsfiddle.net/k5hs8/

Comment: I did but when i go over the link nothing happens

Comment: is there a way to set a timeout? i'm facing a problem. when i switch quickly from one `content` to another it `theLink` hover stop work for both.

Comment: mmm this doesn't sound right, it's not yor fault, it's just timeout it's not the right approch, i've found how it works correctly by placing it in another level (ouside content) using closest->children to get it but it has problem going over the item below. I've tried to set in css anything to let it go over below item with no luck, i also tried to move among other div to find the corret place but nothing worked still. Any clue?

Comment: by the way it does go over border of item below but not the picture wich is called with a normal `<img>`

Comment: Got it, with z-index added in theDiv class while after load by jquery. Thanks for all your support, i really apreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest this:

```
$('.theLink').hover(
    function () {
        $('.theDiv', $(this).parent()).fadeIn();
    },
    function () {
        $('.theDiv', $(this).parent()).hide();
});
```

With this html:

```
<div>
<div class="theLink">Compatibilit&agrave;</div>    
<div class="theDiv">' . $something . '</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Oh sorry, fixed it, had to put $(this) not just this